# Thread Group Loop Count, does it work when all threads in the group are finished?

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

in my JMeter Test Properties, i have number of threads/users: 25
each user takes from 5-10 minutes to finish all the samplers (based on random timer between samplers)
and the Test Loop Count: 3

my question is, does the loop count works when all the threads in the thread groups finishes, or it repeats the threads in the thread group when the thread/user finishes (because that is what i want, to repeat the thread/user when it finishes for  3 times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread is executed independently. It does NOT wait for all other threads to finish its execution. A thread, once finishes its loop 1 execution, it repeats as per the loop count.